# How to skip gaps when using SQL GROUP BY to compute duration

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has ACTIONS with USER and date/time of each action.  A group of Actions by the same user is a session.  I want to measure the duration of each session.  However if there is a gap larger than 5 minutes without any action, then I want to start a new session.

I am using this SQL

```
Select USER,
       TRUNC((Max(ACTION_DATE) - Min(ACTION_DATE))*24*60,2) as Minutes
from USER_ACTION_DATA
Group by USER,TRUNC(ACTION_DATE,'J') ;
```

And it works pretty well if the user only has *one session per day*.  But if the data is

```
USER    ACTION_DATE
---------------------
john    2021-05-24 11:30:22
john    2021-05-24 11:32:12
john    2021-05-24 11:32:44
john    2021-05-24 11:36:08
john    2021-05-24 14:20:02
john    2021-05-24 14:23:52
```

it will show a single session with 173 minutes.  But that is wrong.  It should be two sessions with 6 and 3 minutes (because the gap between the 4th and 5th record is more than 5 minutes).  Is this possible with SQL, or do I have to do the grouping with a real programming language?

Comment: Please add the explanation for 2 sessions with 6 minutes and 3 mintues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you can use `match_recognize`:

```
select user_name,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  trunc((end_date - start_date) * 24 * 60, 2) as minutes
from user_action_data
match_recognize (
  partition by user_name
  order by action_date
  measures
    first(action_date) as start_date,
    last(action_date) as end_date
  pattern (A B*)
  define B as action_date <= prev(action_date) + interval '5' minute
);
```

| USER_NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2021-05-24 11:30:22 | 2021-05-24 11:36:08 | 5.76 |
| john | 2021-05-24 14:20:02 | 2021-05-24 14:23:52 | 3.83 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4749c6183fdce0dc386d98fb82c92eb6)

`USER` is a reserved word (and [a function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/USER.html#GUID-AD0B927B-EFD4-4246-89B4-2D55AB3AF531)) so I've changed the column name to `USER_NAME` to make it valid.

Because it's only looking at the interval it will allow a session to span midnight, rather than restricting to sessions within a day, as you are doing by truncating with J. I'm assuming that's a good thing, of course. If it isn't then you can change it to only look within the same day:

```
  define B as trunc(action_date) = trunc(prev(action_date))
    and action_date <= prev(action_date) + interval '5' minute
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1e9ac15dba9eaade0835ad678c9b1ac) with some additional sample data to go into the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a session using window functions -- check when the previous action is and assigning a session start when needed:

```
select uad.*,
       sum(case when prev_action_date > action_date - interval '5' minute then 0 else 1 end) over 
            (partition by user order by action_date) as session_id
from (select uad.*,
             lag(action_date) over (partition by user order by action_date) as prev_action_date
      from USER_ACTION_DATA uad
     ) uad;
```

You can then aggregate this if you like:

```
select user, min(action_date), max(action_date),
       ( max(action_date) - min(action_date) ) * 24*60*60
from (select uad.*,
               sum(case when prev_action_date > action_date - interval '5' minute then 0 else 1 end) over 
                  (partition by user order by action_date) as session_id
      from (select uad.*,
                   lag(action_date) over (partition by user order by action_date) as prev_action_date
            from USER_ACTION_DATA uad
           ) uad
      ) uad
group by user, session_id;
```